# Singapore medical visa for US citizen

Tags: visas, us-citizens, health, singapore

Can US citizen get medication/emergency surgical procedure under tourist visa?

Comment: Do you want to get a "medical visa" or you want to have a surgery under tourist visa?

Comment: @Dirty-flow It doesn't really matter, in either case they don't need a visa.

Comment: Is this about "can I get medical services?" (yes, of course) or "how does payment for medical services work?"

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether you want to travel to Singapore especially for a medical procedure or whether you are worried that you might need to get medical help while on a tourist visa. In either case, it shouldn't matter in your case:

As a US-citizen, you [do not require a visa](https://www.ica.gov.sg/visitor/visitor_entryvisa) to enter Singapore. You will get a stamp in your passport at arrival with either 30 or 90 days of stay. As long as you don't intend to work in Singapore, this is not bound to a specific purpose, so you can use that to visit a hospital. If you want or need more than the days given to you, you can apply for an [extension](https://www.ica.gov.sg/enteranddeparting/extend/enterandeparting_extend_visit) on medical grounds.

It is fairly common for people to travel to Singapore to seek medical treatment, so most hospitals (here are [two](https://www.mountelizabeth.com.sg/plan-your-visit/international-patient-guide) [examples](https://www.rafflesmedicalgroup.com/international-patients/faq)) will have departments dealing with foreign patients. So if you are unsure, you could contact the hospital in question and they should assist you.